# Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet, proxy, do-release-upgrade

When I want to upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04 Bionic Beaver to 18.10 to Cosmic Cuttlefish via terminal with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` command it gives me warning:

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. 
Check your Internet connection or proxy settings.
```

However I have internet connection, I write this question now from my Ubuntu computer.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 21):

It seems like there is an issue about certificates:

```
result of meta-release download: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)>
```

As a workaround, I edited the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py` and added these lines to the beginning:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: Why would that work?

Comment: @alvas I'm not sure why but I figured out that in my case SSL verification failed. So I applied the workaround to skip SSL verification.

Comment: For months I've been seeing this in my 18.04.4 LTS release, and alas it didn't fix itself as 20.04 LTS became available today. I searched everywhere, including in #ubuntu on freenode. Finally this solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: This fixed it for me on the corporate network that MITMs SSL connections

Comment: This is highly insecure, as it disables SSL certificate validation. The solution described in the other answer is much better as it fixes the underlying issue.

Comment: it works but i feel dirty :D

Answer (score 14):

The problem is the used ca:

```
$ python3 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)'
/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```

The path might be `/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem` for your installation, adjust following commands to use this path if it's your case.

But:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem': No such file or directory
```

You can fix it by linking the global ca-certificates to the file Python uses:

```
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```

After that running `do-release-upgrade` works just fine.

For a temporary solution:

```
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. one simple symlink. I tried upgrading from 16.04 to the current release, and this fixed the updating process. without having to hack the python file.

Comment: Thanks for this. On 20.04 I had to run `sudo update-ca-certificates` then link to `/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem` rather than `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem`, as guided by the output of the python query. Can't account for why `/usr/local...` rather than `/usr/lib...`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: i tried more than dozen tricks from diff website. Nothing worked.  Only the above solution by @Jeremy Field worked.  So it shoudl be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an Ubuntu [bug that has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1771914/comments/8), but I'm not sure if the patch will be available in updates for 18.04.2 LTS.

From 2018:

> update-manager (1:18.10.3) cosmic; urgency=medium
>
> - Add support for HTTPS proxies; this breaks
>     UpdateManager.Core.utils.init_proxy()
>     API - the return value is now a dict, rather than a string (LP: #1771914).
>     ...
>     The verification of the Stable Release Update for update-manager has completed successfully and the package has now been released to -updates.

Comment: I had a version > 18.04.2 (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) however still it did not work. Above solution of updating  MetaRelease.py fixed it.