# Cannot upgrade ubuntu: Failed to connect (when inet is fine)

Tags: upgrade, updates, 20.04, openssl

I'm trying to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04, following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes. I have run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and have set `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version`. However, nothing in the release notes worked.

`update-manager -c` says everything up to date, but says: 
`Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings`. 
Same for `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk` or `do-release-upgrade`. `sudo apt dist-upgrade` does nothing.
However, when i can `curl` the url and it loads fine in firefox.

Maybe relevant: I have compiled and installed openssl 1.1.1g by hand. Maybe some difference between openssl 1.1.1c and 1.1.1g is causing this error? I compiled with `./config zlib zlib-dynamic threads enable-buildtest-c++ --release`

How would I fix this?

Edit: I have no proxy or internet issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it somehow hadn't occurred to me to google the error message ;(

After some googling, I found [Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072819/failed-to-connect-to-https-changelogs-ubuntu-com-meta-release-development-che/1086496).

So, after editing `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py`, it worked.

However, I'm on ubuntu 19.10, and the issue in that question seems to have fixed in ubuntu 18.04.2.

The problem seems to have been something not playing nicely with `https`. In the question's case something to do with the certs, but in my case i can `curl` it and `openssl s_client` has no problem verifying the cert, but then again the `update-manager` and others might be doing something weird.

Might be the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your computer has IPv6, check if your IPv6 connectivity is working.

changelogs.ubuntu.com has an AAAA entry:
try pinging changelogs.ubuntu.com

```
ping6 -c1 changelogs.ubuntu.com
```

Otherwise verify that with your installation of SSL the connection works:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -showcerts -connect changelogs.ubuntu.com:443 < /dev/null
```

The output should start with:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = changelogs.ubuntu.com
verify return:1
```

Comment: I don't think my isp has ipv6: `ping6: connect: Network is unreachable`. The openssl s_client works.

Comment: Try to empty this file: /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
just type (in root or with sudo)   > /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available or delete it then retry update-manager or do-release-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my name server was changed when I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 18

Once it is changed my `/etc/resolv.conf` file, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a customer's computer with Ubuntu 18.04. After reading this thread and [Upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 fails because of HTTPS certificate issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/yajzo2/upgrade_2004_to_2204_fails_because_of_https/), which is about the same issue, I checked wget's response and there was the same validity error regarding the website's certificate. A `dpkg-reconfigure -plow ca-certificates` did not fix the problem, although all the necessary certificates had been enabled. I then checked `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` and discovered that the DST Root CA X3 certficate had been disabled. I then removed the exclamation mark in front of it, re-ran `update-ca-certificates`, and then everything worked.

Because that file looked so weird and did not match the output of `dpkg-reconfigure`, I ended up deleting `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` completely and re-created it by another run of `dpkg-reconfigure -plow ca-certificates`. Everything was fine after that.

The system was a pre-configured one.