# Trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 and then 19.04

Tags: 18.04

Okay this should be easy but it seems unusually difficult.  I have an Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) AWS EC2 instance which I want to upgrade.  I realise that I'll have to do it in two steps but I'm having a few issues, as follows.

I've done quite a bit of research on this so here's what I've done:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available

Edited /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt= from lts to normal.

sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

**Tried:** sudo do-release-upgrade
**Result:** Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new release found.

**Tried:** sudo do-release-upgrade -d
**Result:** Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.

I can curl to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development with no problems.

I've restarted the Server a few times and tried to repeat the process, with no luck.  I even found an article that recommended editing a dist-upgrade related Python file with an SSL related setting.  This didn't fix the issue so I backed that edit out again.

I suspect that if 18.10 or 19.04 were recorded as LTS then I'd be able to upgrade to them but that doesn't help me at the moment.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  I'd rather not build a fresh Server at this stage (although I need to convert the build to IaC in the future).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as [I read from this discussion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391641)

> `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` actually calls `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`.
>   If you run `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`, that's the script that fails with the error message.

some other user fixed the issue running

> All I did to make it go away was: `sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`

The [same problem was experienced with 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/994024/650195)

> The script will only update the file every 24 hours. So if you wait long enough, the file will go stale and the script will update the file anyway. But,if you want to update it immediately, just remove `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` and run `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade` and it should start working correctly.

Happy to help you further

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio.  Unfortunately that didn't work.  The same issues remain.  BTW per above I've already tried removing the release-upgrade-available file.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: I found no way around this so I ended up building a brand new 19.04 Server using an official AWS image off cloud-images.ubuntu.com.  I had to remember the DevOps mantra: Servers are cattle not pets!  The rebuild me has forced me to recheck my config so it's now alot easier for me to rebuild it in future via Terraform.

Comment: @ChrisFNZ I am sorry. That is unlucky. I could not help any further. Thanks !

Comment: funny this is not fixed yet. am facing the same problem