# Trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 get 'failed to connect..." error

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade, 20.10

I get the following error message when I try to upgrade to 20.10:

'Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings'

I can display the contents of the file in chrome.

I have tried deleting and regenerating the motd file as described at [failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919441/failed-to-connect-to-http-changelogs-ubuntu-com-meta-release) to no effect.

I am using 'sudo do-release-upgrade -c' to do the upgrade, I have also tried 'sudo update-manager' to no effect.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error message.  However I tried again and eventually the install started.

I used Alt F2 and `update-manager -c` as explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/351360/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I  the problem by removing python2-minimal and a few other things.